# Woocommerce Products and Category pages have different templates from other WC pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website that is using WooCommerce to sell items. Here is my demo site:

http://demo.bergdahl.com/

You can see the ecommerce pages and their layouts here:

**Layout 1 (left and right sidebars):**
Products list: http://demo.bergdahl.com/shop/
Category page: http://demo.bergdahl.com/product-category/catridges/

**Layout 2 (right sidebar only):**
Single product page: http://demo.bergdahl.com/product/6-oz-catridge/

I have gotten it so that most of the WooCommerce pages use have layout 1 except the *single product page* that has layout 2. Layout 2 is set to be the default layout in the theme and applies to the other 170 pages of the site. I don't want to change the default layout, I just want to find out what page I can use to set the layout for the single product page.

Basically, I would like to have all WC pages use layout 1.

*My question is, how does WooCommerce chose which layout is assigned to which type of page?*

It seems like the Product list and the Category pages are pulled in from the blog page layout. The Cart, Checkout, and My Account pull from their actual pages. **I am not sure how to set the layout in the single product page.**

P.S. - This site uses an older theme with no WC support. I don't know if this may be the problem but I could only adapt the theme by using the woocommerce_content() method listed here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/?utm_source=notice&utm_medium=product&utm_content=themecompatibility&utm_campaign=woocommerceplugin

Answer (score 1):

You can override the singe product template.

To override the single product template, copy: 
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product to 
wp-content/themes/Builder/woocommerce/single-product

There is an official documentation for WooCommerce theme override at [Template Structure + overriding template](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)s via a theme.

Comment: I understand overriding template files but this actually comes from my theme. There is a box on the bottom left that allows me to select a "layout" which is created elsewhere. It is very similar to the standard WordPress templates area. This is how I got the cart, checkout, and my-account pages to change to use my "layout". With the product list and categories page, I just had to change the "layout" on the blog page. I was wondering if there is another page like this that I could add my layout to for the single product page.

Comment: You got me thinking, is there a way to hook my exisitng sidebars and page layout into the single product page? The theme the client is using is very convoluted but maybe there is some standard wordpress hooks or code?

Comment: Hi Matt, try adding wp-content/themes/Builder/woocommerce/single-product.php with this [template code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product.php) Add get_sidebar() or dymanic_sidebar('sidebar_name_here') to display sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lax, I found a way around it. I actually used the woocommerce.php that I created out of my theme's page.php. This got it out of the same container that the product was in.

I then used the `dynamic_sidebar('sidebar_name_here')` to display the sidebar on that page . The full code I used was:

```
<?php if(is_product()){?>
  <div class="store-sidebar-left">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('store-sidebar-left');?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This allows it to only show on the single product page.

I had one small problem where I couldn't find the name of the sidebar in my theme or my database so I just created a new on in my functions.php file and used that one.